# How to emulate the Bluetooth command(s) of another Android app

Tags: bluetooth

So, I have a Honda generator that communicates to my Android phone / tablet via a Honda Power Equipment app called "My Generator".  One of the features of the My Generator app (new to this generator) is the ability to turn it off remotely via a Bluetooth connection.  There is a button on the Honda app that you hold down for 1.5 seconds and all connected generators turn off.  This is particularly handy when camping and there is bad weather out.

Now, my research so far tells me that I cannot use an automation app to "push" that button, as the apps are isolated from each other and that ability would be a security violation.

However, since the Honda app sends a Bluetooth command to the four generators, is it possible to capture that command (or commands) and then have or develop my own app to do the same thing?

My intent in doing this is that I want to be able to turn off the generators at a specific time of day or after a specific amount of time has passed and the Honda app does not off such a feature.

Lacking much knowledge of Android programming in general (I'm more of a C++ guy), how or where would I start to do this, if it can even be done?

I appreciate any and all answers, even if they are not what I necessarily want to hear.  Thanks.

Scott

Comment: There are 2 ways to do what you need: 1. Use Bluetooth sniffer. 2. Use "emulator". The details depends on Bluetooth used by generator: Classic or LE

Comment: So, I have decided NOT to try to emulate or re-create the bluetooth command that turns off the genrator(s).  I have four of these and figured out a way to turn them off remotely using a hardwired cable and a simple clock / timer with a relay.  The downside is that it turns ALL off at the same time, but after thought, I realized that it would be rare for me to turn 1 or 2 off without turning them all off.

So, please consider this question to be closed.  I do NOT intend to investigate and/or replicate the bluetooth commands that do the same thing.  Thank you for the reply.

Scott